# Example for IFA_TTLLLBINARY

Tags: iso8583, jpos, tlv

Hey i'm a `Jpos` newbie and i'm having  a problem with a field that's using the `IFA_TTLLLBINARY`

```
    ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
    isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
    isoMsg1.setMTI("0100");
    //...
    isoMsg.set(55 ,"6F1A840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A5088801025F2D02656E");

    //...

    logISOMsg(isoMsg);

    byte[] data = isoMsg.pack();
    System.out.println("RESULT : " + new String(data));
```

but i always get this error :

[image]

Can anyone tell me the reason why this error is showing .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/test/java/org/jpos/iso/packager/TaggedFieldPackagerBaseTest.java
as a starting point.

Comment: i'm actually working with the `Jpos 1.9.6` version but can't find the  **TaggedFieldPackagerBaseTest.java** nowhere !

Comment: what holds you on moving to 2.0.0?

Comment: Nothing actually, what are the main differences @apr  ?